# How to reference a React hooks component after publishing to npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, build, package.json

I have published a React component to npm lets call it `anew-lib` but the config forces full path which I would like to eliminate

This works:

```
import Obj from "anew-lib"; // DOES NOT WORK :(
import Obj from "anew-lib/dist/cjs/components/Obj"; // WORKS!
```

[image]

package.json

```json
{
   "name": "anew-lib",
   "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
   "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
   "files": [
      "dist"
   ],
   "scripts": {
      "build": "rm -rf dist/ && prettier --write src/ && npm run build:esm && npm run build:cjs",
      "build:esm": "tsc",
      "build:cjs": "tsc --module CommonJS --outDir dist/cjs"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
      "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
      "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.8",
      "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
      "react": "^18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
      "typescript": "^4.8.4"
   },
   "peerDependencies": {
      "react": "^18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
   }
}
```